# Not able to import csv file to pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[Error consisting of word 'columns'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWsne.png)

I am trying to upload a csv file into pgAdmin, but it shows the above error, I have tried opening other csv files also, but everytime getting this error.

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages. They're not searchable, and frankly, it's just as easy for you, and better for us, to copy and paste them.

Comment: That is certainly an unhelpful error message.  Is this the latest version of pgAdmin?  If you click over to the 'columns' tab of the dialog, what do you see?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular in this case the screen shot seems appropriate.  Given the uselessness of the error message, I probably wouldn't have believed it without seeing it in context.